# Connector/j и JDBC - это одно и то же?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, jdbc, mysqlconnector

Как я понял и MySQL Connector/j и JDBC являются библиотеками для работы с БД, но JDBC - это общее название драйверов, которые используются в java для работы с БД, а Connector/j называют драйвер java для работы именно с MySQL.

Comment: JDBC - это набор интерфейсов, а Connector/j - их реализация, для работы с mysqll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JDBC (англ. Java DataBase Connectivity — соединение с базами данных на
>   Java) — платформенно независимый промышленный стандарт взаимодействия
>   Java-приложений с различными СУБД, реализованный в виде пакета
>   java.sql, входящего в состав Java SE.